# rfid mysql query to python

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

I have an old php system that uses Rfid. We have a sql query which converts the Rfid codes. I am changing the PHP system to ODOO 11 Here is the SQL query

```
UPDATE members set member_id=100000*floor(fob_id/65536)+(fob_id%65536)
```

It is basically the fob id multiplied by 100000 then divided by 65536
But later they discovered if a fob number ended with a 7 or 9 i think, it was being calculated wrong so the floor part always rounds down and the % adds on the remainder after dividing them. (I think is how it worked)

How can I get the same result in Python as the above query (Python version 3.5)

Here is my code

```py
@api.onchange('barcode2')
def _onchange_barcode2(self):
    self.barcode = (self.barcode2)
    a = (self.barcode2) * 100000 
    fob = (math.floor(a)) /65536 +(self.barcode2)%65536
    self.memberid = fob
```

I have a rfid number of 0005225306 which should be 07947962 but with the above code I get 8,021,146.

Am I using the % operator correct? If I input 0005225306 into my old PHP system which uses MySQL `UPDATE members set member_id=100000*floor(fob_id/65536)+(fob_id%65536)`it gives correct value of 07947962.

Any idea why my python code is not getting the same value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about your `barcode*` fields and their data type, but care when parsing them. And the order of those calculations is important:

```py
@api.onchange('barcode2')
def _onchange_barcode2(self):
    # let's suppose the barcode fields are strings
    # because of leading zeros
    self.barcode = self.barcode2
    try:
        barcode_int = int(self.barcode2)
        fob = math.floor(barcode_int / 65536)
        fob = int((fob * 100000) + barcode_int % 65536)
        # let's suppose memberid is a char field
        self.memberid = '{:08d}'.format(fob)
    except:
        # handle parse problems eg. Odoo Warning
```

Comment: `@api.onchange('barcode2')
    def _onchange_barcode2(self):
        self.barcode = (self.barcode2)
        # try:
        barcode_int = int(self.barcode2)
        fob = math.floor(barcode_int / 65536)
        fob = (fob * 100000) + barcode_int % 65336
        self.memberid = fob  # care for float numbers here!
        # except:`
Above code gives different value but is still wrong. It gives value of 7,963,762

Comment: I've mixed up a number in 65536 (was 65336 in the modulo part). I also added string formatting to get the desired output.